# sql request Max Group by

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hi guys Could you help me.
Please find below images with input and output data
So I need to code sql request to show only the maximum date in each competence_question_id, and also show a value of competence_answer_id with this date (I also have grouping  by response_id but i hide it here)

Thank you in advance

```
SELECT response_id, competence_question_id, competence_answer_id, MAX(date_created)
FROM competence_vote_history
WHERE response_id = 53178
GROUP BY response_id, competence_question_id, competence_answer_id
ORDER BY response_id, competence_question_id
```

[the table one with input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WtmO.jpg)

[the table two with output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzfeZ.jpg)

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query for the desired result.

```
SELECT competence_question_id, competence_answer_id, date_created, answer_value
FROM competence_vote_history i
WHERE response_id = 53178 
    AND date_created = (
        SELECT MAX(date_created) 
        FROM competence_vote_history 
        WHERE response_id = i.response_id 
        AND competence_question_id = i.competence_question_id)
ORDER BY response_id, competence_question_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If the date_created column doesn't have the date repeated, then you can use a derived table (where the max(date_created) is obtained for the competence_question_id) joined back to the original table:

```
SELECT V.*
  FROM (
         SELECT competence_question_id, MAX(date_created) AS MAXdate_created
           FROM competence_vote_history
          WHERE response_id = 53178
         GROUP BY competence_question_id
       ) AS dT INNER JOIN competence_vote_history V on dT.competence_question_id = V.competence_question_id
                                                   AND dT.MAXdate_created = V.date_created
ORDER BY response_id, competence_question_id
```